# differentiation with respect to vector

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ a vector, and $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$
a symmetric matrix depending on $x$
I need to find a way to differentiate $p(x) = x^t A(x) x \in $ with respect to 
$x$. This should be a 1 by $n$ vector.

I tried the following
\begin{align}
\frac{d p(x)}{d x} & = \frac{d x^t A(x) x }{d x} \\
& = \frac{d x^t}{d x} A(x) x + x^t \frac{d A(x) x }{d x}
\end{align}
But I think this is already incorrect because the first term can't be an 1 by $n$ vector anymore. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: The derivative of such functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ is usually interpreted as being the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) $\mathrm{grad}\; p$.

Comment: @M.Winter The gradient takes scalar functions as inputs, not vectors. OP, see [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorFcnsCalculus.aspx).

Comment: @Lovsovs: That's probably what he meant. The derivative of mentioned function ( which is a scalar valued function ). Not that the gradient takes us to $\mathbb R$, but the derivative of a function that takes us to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @mathreadler Ah, my bad.

Comment: Also the gradient can in fact be computed for a vector though the resulting object is more complicated

Comment: @Triatticus: Yes, you can do that and get a "matrix" in some sense. Just add one index. Like a tensor outer product with nabla.

Comment: In index notation, the gradient is $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_k}=2A_{ki}x_i+x_ix_j\Bigg(\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial x_k}\Bigg)$$

Comment: Yeah I just call it a dayad/tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of such functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$ is usually interpreted as being the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) $\mathrm{grad}\; p$. When rewriting $p$ in components

$$x^\top A(x)x=\sum_{i,j}x_ix_jA_{ij}(x)$$

you can apply the gradients definition immediately. Let $\partial_k$ be the partial derivative w.r.t. the $k$-th component of $x$, then

\begin{align}
\partial_k p(x)
&=\sum_j(x_jA_{kj}(x)+x_kx_j[\partial_kA_{kj}(x)])+\sum_{i\not=k,j}x_ix_j[\partial_kA_{ij}(x)]\\
&=\sum_jx_jA_{kj}(x)+\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j[\partial_kA_{ij}(x)]\\
&=e_k^\top A(x)x+x^\top [\partial_kA(x)] x.
\end{align}

Take these together to a vector to obtain

$$\text{grad }p(x) = A(x)x+(\partial_1A(x)x \;\cdots\; \partial_nA(x)x)^\top x,$$

where in the second term there is this matrix with rows $\partial_kA(x)x$ (after transposing).

Comment: ok, it seems to be correct. Thank you!